# All subcolumns for multiple supercolumns against a key in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, thrift, thrift-protocol

Can we read list of all available subcolumns for multiple supercolumns against a key in one request.

for example

we have a key "y1" with supercolumns x1,x2,x3

x1 has subcolumns with names like c1,c2,c3
x2 has subcolumns c9 and c8
x3 has c1,c3,c10

I want to read all the subcolumns in one request against one key "y1".

Comment: also please show us how this is possible in composite key layout........when we have varying c1,c2...cN..........dynamic not known earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a super slice query and specify a range.  Here's a Hector example:

```
SuperSliceQuery query = HFactory.createSuperSliceQuery(keyspace, ... serializers ...);
query.setColumnFamily(columnFamily)
     .setKey(key)
     .setRange("", "", false, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thanks rs_atl, now i have switched to composite columns.